# JQuery Mobile search box background color

Tags: css, search, jquery-mobile, input, colors

Hi all I am trying to change the background colour of my search box. It is currently white and I want to be able to change it to a custom color. I have tried a few different techniques but the background color doesnt seem to fill the entire search box and leaves white at both ends of the search field. I also want to be able to have a custom image at the start of the search box therefore pushing the placeholder text over to the right a bit. I have also tried this using padding etc but again I havent had any luck. Any help would be really appreciated. The code I am using for the search box can be found below:

CSS:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #424242;
}
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #424242;
}

#search_controls input.ui-input-text{
    background: url("../../images/search.jpg") 1% no-repeat !important;
    background-color: #2ECCFA !important;
    outline: 0;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="search_controls">
 <input type="number" class="search-box" placeholder="Number" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please choose a correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct but you have a little mistake in CSS selector `input.ui-input-text`. It should be either `div.ui-input-text` or `.ui-input-text`.

Also, search input is different than other types of input. The surrounding div has class `.ui-input-search`.

```
.ui-input-text, .ui-input-search {
 background: url("../../images/search.jpg") 1% no-repeat !important;
 background-color: #2ECCFA !important;
 outline: 0
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/22hCL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-image: url("../../images/search.jpg") 1% no-repeat !important;
background-color: #2ECCFA !important;
```

Comment: That still doesnt fill the entire input box I think I should have mentioned I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I've never played with JQuery UI before, but I'm guessing your issue comes from a mismatch of the classes you've provided. Your CSS is looking to style an `input` element with `class="ui-input-text"` nested inside your `div` with `id="search_controls"`..

try just 
`#search_controls input.search-box{/* -- styles -- */}`